# How can i define a function that reads and returns all values in the list using Python?

Tags: python, loops, user-defined-functions

I have this string delimited by commas.

```
'1.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0'

def var():
   for i in listnumbers:
       return i +'.0'
```

When I do

```
var()
```

I only get

```
1.0
```

How do i get the result to include all the numbers in a loop?

```
1.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0
```

Comment: Your function is only returning one value because the return statement is *in* the loop so it returns on the first iteration. You should try to collect the values in the loop then when the loop finishes return the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def myfun(mycsv): 
    return [i+'.0' for i in mycsv.split(',')] 

print(myfun('1.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0'))

#['1.0.0', '5.0.0', '6.0.0', '7.0.0', '8.0.0', '9.0.0']
```

If you want a string, then just use join:

```
print(','.join(myfun('1.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0')))
```

Or change the function to return a string;

```
return ','.join([i+'.0' for i in mycsv.split(',')])
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep it as a string? Here it turns into a list.

Comment: edited to answer, you should read a bit more of how python works

Answer (score 1):

You are returning inside the for loop, before the cycle is completed.

If I understood correctly your question, it looks like what you're looking for is list comprehension.

If your input is a list:

```
def var(l):
  return [i + '.0' for i in l]
```

If your input is a string, like it seems from your description, you have to split it first:

```
def var(l):
  return [i + '.0' for i in l.split(',')]
```

This is equivalent to `map`ping in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can divide your string in a list using `string.split(',')` the you iterate over the freshly created list and print each element. A the code can be arranged like this:

```
for s in string.split(','):
    print(s+'.0')
```